# How to delete a specific item created from map in react?

Tags: reactjs

A user can add more inputs to their form to add more information. Let's say they created three inputs and filled them out. Then they decided to delete the second one, but keep the first and third. What would the function be to delete this specific one?

I've been scratching my head on this for a while now and couldn't come up with a good solution.

### Tech

- React
- Next.js
- Material-UI

### The Code

In my code, I have a button that adds more components to the list but increasing the number by one. Then I create an Array with `[...Array(amount)]` and map that to display the right amount of components.

Codesandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/kitty-inputs-g91f6

This is a basic example of what I want. Each input has a button for deleting that specific component, just the logic to delete it is missing.

### The Issue

Now the issue is, I don't know how to delete a specific component created that way.
My first idea was to save the components in a state array and delete them like that, but that is not something being recommended.

So this is why I am reaching to StackOverflow.

Comment: imho, you should maintain an array of kitties on `App.js`, and change your `input.js` to just render the design of each component. With that you can have addKitty, removeKitty, updateKitty within `App.js` as single source of truth

Comment: @Isaac You're saying that instead of the component itself holding the value, App should hold the value and I just delete the value from that state if I delete a component? That could work, I will experiment.

Comment: you can take a look at my answer but of course feel free to challenge yourself to it too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-lederberg-gxe66?file=/src/App.js

For your `input.js` try to keep it simple as below

```js
import React from "react";

export function Input({ kitty, handleDelete, handleChange }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="kitty-name">Kitty's Name</label>
        <br />
        <button onClick={handleDelete} type="button">
          Delete this specific input
        </button>
      </div>
      <input
        id="kitty-name"
        type="text"
        value={kitty.name}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Basically the idea is that, `Input` component only knows how a single kitty should render and what events to support, such as `handleDelete`

Now in your `App.js` you can then maintain the list of `kitties` as below

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { Input } from "./Input";
import { useState } from "react";
import catNames from "cat-names";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

export default function App() {
  const [kitties, setKitties] = useState([]);

  const handleAdd = () => {
    setKitties([...kitties, { id: nanoid(), name: catNames.random() }]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello Stack Overflow</h1>
      <h2>How to delete specific inputs created through map?</h2>
      <form>
        {kitties.map((kitty) => (
          <Input
            key={kitty.id}
            kitty={kitty}
            handleChange={(event) => {
              const newKitties = kitties.map((x) =>
                x.id === kitty.id ? { ...x, name: event.target.value } : x
              );
              setKitties([...newKitties]);
            }}
            handleDelete={() => {
              const newKitties = kitties.filter((x) => x.id !== kitty.id);
              setKitties([...newKitties]);
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </form>
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add more Kitties</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain a cat List state in the App.js and handle the delete, update and add on this state .

Since the cats state is now an array , you can easily manipulate the values or remove them using `index`

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Input } from "./Input";
import { useState } from "react";

import catNames from "cat-names";

export default function App() {
  const [cats, setCats] = useState([]);

  const handleAdd = () => {
    setCats((existingCats) => [...existingCats, catNames.random()]);
  };

  const onInputChange = (catname, index) => {
    const newCatList = [...cats];
    newCatList[index] = catname;
    setCats(newCatList);
  };

  const handleDelete = (indexToDelete) => {
    setCats((existingCats) =>
      existingCats.filter((_, index) => index !== indexToDelete)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello Stack Overflow</h1>
      <h2>How to delete specific inputs created through map?</h2>
      <form>
        {cats.map((_, i) => (
          <Input
            key={i}
            handleDelete={() => handleDelete(i)}
            value={cats[i]}
            handleChange={(e) => onInputChange(e.target.value, i)}
          />
        ))}
      </form>
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add more Kitties</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-frog-ynhgx?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing array of inputs length (`amount`), store an array of inputs:

```
const [inputArr, setInputArr] = useState([]);
```

Each `inputArr`'s element would have data like this:

```
inputArr = [{
    key: '...',
    answer: '',
    type: 'text', //this will help you if you are going to support various type of input like text, number, date, checkbox, ...
}]
```

Please note that the `key` key is required for `Array.map` in React ([Read this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)).
As your requirement, you don't have anything candidate for `key`, so I suggest to use `Math.random` as key.

```
inputArr.push({ key: (''+ Math.random()).slice(2), answer: '', type: 'text' })
```

Then when you want to modify the inputs, you just need to find the input element base on `key`

Final code:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kitty-inputs-forked-ig5id?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Instead of using key as you did, I would suggest just use ID and use the ID as the key, which has the same effect in the end. Every input already gets an ID, so it works.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of great answers here. Here is another solution to this problem I have come up with:

https://codesandbox.io/s/kitty-inputs-experiments-ppfb5?file=/src/App.js

I created an array of objects that each holds the inputs `id`, `name` and `value`. That way I can later pass it to another function to save it somewhere else with its proper information, mainly `name` and `value`.